# Localhost is different from 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, apache

I started developing a website from a book so I needed on my laptop Apache 2, PHP 5 and MySQL 4.1 because that is what's recommended to ensure programming works correctly (database queries, php scripts, etc). Initially I downloaded Apache 2.4.34 win64 VC15 and configured the httpd to start on "localhost". After that, I run the command prompt, accessed the directory and typed httpd.exe -k install to then run the Apache server. Everything worked fine and when I accessed localhost in web browser I got a a webpage with message "It works!". Whenever I turned off the Apache server, this message was still showing in localhost so it was weird. The problem I am facing now is that I uninstalled the Apache 2.4.34 win64 VC15, I also removed it from the firewall settings to then install XAMPP for Windows 5.6.36. After changing again the httpd file for XAMPP, I have one big issue:
when I run in the browser 127.0.0.1 I'm getting to access my website. 
When I run localhost I'm still getting the old web page with "It works!" message even tho I don't have it anymore?

Operating system: Windows 10 64bits

Comment: @NigelRen That question is about MySQL connecting to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, this one however, is about two different pages being served when accessing `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Sorry - but TBH I'm not sure what the question is about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because your browser has cached `http://localhost`. Clear your browser cache, or force re request the resources by pressing `F5` - in Firefox - while your on the page

your browser networking monitor should be always opened while you are developing to see what is going on

Comment: `Ctrl` + `F5` maybe?

Comment: @Nima I do it with just `F5` on my Firefox 61 on linux

Comment: That does not force a cache override, it might cause it but does not enforce it. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation

Comment: @Nima You are right,  thanks for the reference. So `F5` Reloads and `CTRL` + `F5` Reloads (override cache)